# How to change the way a value is displayed in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have websites being saved to a field called `website` that you can put the value of `www.website.com` or use `http://www.website.com`. I'm not sure how you make the  `http://www.website.com` always look like `www.website.com` in the view.

If my model is `Store` and its table column is `t.string :website`. What would I put in my StoreHelper and view? Is it possible to change a string like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get rid of the `http://` part:

```
@store.website.downcase.sub(/https?:\/\//, '')
```

Personally, I wouldn't do it in a helper, but add a method to my model:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  def website_without_http
    self.website.downcase.sub(/https?:\/\//, '')
  end
end
```

With this you can do:

```
<%= link_to @store.website_without_http, @store.website %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a helper to do something like:

```
def website_pretty_display(url)
  # strip out the http, etc
  new_url
end
```

then in the view, you can do:

```
link_to website_pretty_display(store.website), store.website
```